# Auto-updating scope variables in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scope

I'm currently playing with AngularJS. I'd like to return, from a service, a variable that will let the scope know when it has changed.

To illustrate this, have a look at the example from www.angularjs.org, "Wire up a backend". Roughly, we can see the following:

```
var projects = $firebase(new Firebase("http://projects.firebase.io"));
$scope.projects = projects;
```

After this, all updates made to the `projects` object (through updates, be it locally or remotely) will be automatically reflected on the view that the scope is bound to.

How can I achieve the same in my project? In my case, I want to return a "self-updating" variable from a service.

```
var inbox = inboxService.inboxForUser("fred");
$scope.inbox = inbox;
```

What mechanisms let the `$scope` know that it should update?

**EDIT:** 
In response to the suggestions, I tried a basic example. My controller:

```
$scope.auto = {
    value: 0
};

setInterval(function () {
    $scope.auto.value += 1;
    console.log($scope.auto.value);
}, 1000);
```

And, somewhere in my view:

```
<span>{{auto.value}}</span>
```

Still, it only displays 0. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

I made a demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dmu5ucEztpfFwsletrYW?p=preview
I use `$timeout` to fake updates.

---

The trick is to use plain javascript references:

- You need to pass an object to the scope.
- You mustn't override that object, just update or extend it.
- If you do override it, you lose the "binding".
- If you use `$http` it will trigger a digest for you.
- So, whenever a change occurs, the scope variable reference to same object that gets updated in the service, and all the watchers will be notified with a digest.
- AFAIK, That's how `$firebase` & `Restangular` work.
- If you do multiple updates you need to have a way of resetting properties.
- Since you hold a reference to an object across the application, you need to be aware of memory leaks.

#### For example:

**Service:**

```
app.factory('inboxService', function($http){

  return {
    inboxForUser: function(user){

      var inbox = {};

      $http.get('/api/user/' + user).then(function(response){
        angular.extend(inbox, response.data);
      })

      return inbox; 
    }
  };
});
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('ctrl', function(inboxService){
  $scope.inbox = inboxService.inboxForUser("fred");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried to apply your solution (update the object) as illustrated in my edited question, but couldn't get it to work. Any idea?

Comment: @Antoine_935 can you share a plunker so I'll take a look?

Comment: Hmmm. Making this plunker made me realise that I should probably use $timeout instead for this example. Alright then, it should work :) http://plnkr.co/edit/OWjMT9hWCn4ujjCnc7eQ?p=preview Thanks for showing me plunker btw, didn't know it!

Comment: But then, should I call `$digest` myself? (as maybe no one will in my case). How should I call it, if I don't have a scope at hand? Not sure I want to call it on the `$rootScope`, it may be heavy.

Comment: Even if you trigger $apply on any scope it would always trigger a digest on the $rootScope anyway. That's a know issue and the angular team is currently working on a solution.

Comment: Oh right, I can use $timeout to wrap my update. Doesn't sound too clean though. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: $timeout by default triggers another digest cycle , see my update.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how the object is updating. If it gets updated "within" angular, a digest cycle will be triggered (See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), and the view will update automatically. That is the beauty of Angular.

If the object gets updated "outside" of angular (e.g. a jQuery plugin), then you can manually trigger a digest cycle by wrapping the code that's doing the updating in an `$apply` function. Something like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    //my non angular code
});
```

See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) for more info.