# AngularJS a scope variable is not updated in an anonymous callback function in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dom-events, cubism.js

I've been trying to make a cubism.js graph with polled data (every second) from REST API.

It seems like a correct value is passed to the directive, but it is not passed to an anonymous callback function.

If I am understanding correctly, the anonymous callback function in directive should have an access to the parameter variable `val`.

The correct value is updated in the view, and the rest of the directive. However, right now it seems like the parameter value, `val`, which was updated from the controller when the promise resolves to a callback function `notifyCall(data)`, is not being updated at an anonymous callback function of directive.

Methods I tried:

- putting the `random` function inside of `notifyCallback` function in the controller.
   -> didn't work
- wrapping `$scope.$apply` on `$scope.sysHeapMemoryPercent`
   -> `$digest error`
- using scope.watch in the directive instead of `attrs.$observe`
   -> had a same result as `attrs.$observe` method

How can I solve this problem? Do I need to use a closure?

**Controller**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('adminControllers')
.controller('pollerController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'poller', function ($scope, $resource, poller) {

  $scope.sysHeapMemoryPercent=0;

  // ......
  // Some codes that makes polling API calls every second
  // using $resource and Angular Poller
  // ......

  myPoller.promise.then({}, {}, notifyCallback); 

  function notifyCallback(data){
    $scope.sysHeapMemoryPercent = Number(data[0].value.used) / Number(data[0].value.max);
    }
}]);
```

**Directive**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('adminControllers')
 .directive('sysHeapMemoryDirective', function ($timeout) {

 return {
 restrict: 'AE',
 link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var context = cubism.context().serverDelay(0).clientDelay(0).step(1000).size(594);


  attrs.$observe('memory', function (newVal,oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal); // prints undefined every second
    console.log(newVal); // prints the correct value every second

    var constantNum = 0.123;
    compute(constNum); // works
    compute(newVal); // Doesn't work. Some child values are returned as null
  });


  function compute(val) {
    var value = 0, values = [],
    i = 0, last; 

    console.log(val); // prints the correct value every second

    return context.metric(function (start, stop, step, callback) {
      start = +start, stop = +stop;

      console.log(val); // prints 0 every second

      if (isNaN(last)) last = start;
      while (last < stop) {
        last += step;
        values.push(val);
      }
      callback(null, values = values.slice((start - stop) / step));
    }, "Demo");
  }
}
};
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="pollerController">
 {{sysHeapMemoryPercent}}  // successfully shows the updated value every second
   <sys-heap-memory-directive memory="{{sysHeapMemoryPercent}}"> </sys-heap-memory-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly.  Is it `sysHeapMemoryPercent` that is not updating?  I'd try wrapping the assignment statement in a call to `$timeout(function(){ ... });

Comment: sysHeapMemoryPercent was updating correctly, but the anonymous callback function, compute(val), did not read the updated value from the parameter because it was not an OBJECT. For some reason, when I wrapped the variable as an object, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to answer my own question, but I found the solution as I was trying other ways to solve the problem.

The problem here is that AngularJS's "dirty-checking" is based on objects, and I was trying to save     *$scope.sysHeapMemoryPercent* as a primitive type (number) not an object.

This link helped me a lot to understand how AngularJS updates scope variables behind the scene.
[Auto-updating scope variables in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562654/auto-updating-scope-variables-in-angularjs)

When I wrapped my response as an object, it worked fine!

```
$scope.sysHeapMemoryPercent={};
// .............
function notifyCallback(data){
  $scope.sysHeapMemoryPercent.value = Number(data[0].value.used) / Number(data[0].value.max);
}
```